# Unload Prism module using unity?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

Is possible to unload module from prism Application after use ?

I am planing to create separate modules for separate products. When load new product , first unload current product (Module ) and load new product (Module). is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot unload modules or any other individual assemblies within the same app domain: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/62c9a223-edf3-4349-b099-00a363b4507e/unload-modules-in-prism?forum=silverlightnet

[WPF Prism - Manage Modules In Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898269/wpf-prism-manage-modules-in-application)

The easiest thing to do is probably to just "hide" the removed product from your UI and implement some kind of authorization to determine which users are allowed to use which modules.